# MongoTimeoutException when trying to insert using Spring boot application app on openshift

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, openshift, spring-data-mongodb

**Issue**:
    1. I am not using Spring Boot MongoAutoConfiguration because we need mongo to be optional. 
    2. Other applications in same namespace can access MongoDB and network namespace is same for Application namespace and database namespace.
    3. When I try to connect I get timeout exception. 
    4. Same worked on my local

**POINTS ALREADY VERIFIED:**
    1. Checked mongod is up and running. other app in same namepsace is able to access same but its using Spring Mongo implementation.
    2. no network issue.
    3. There are post in stackoverflow for same exception, Its already tested. Not working.

**a) application.properties:**

```
mongo.hosts = mongo-node-1.database, mongo-node-2.database, mongo-node-3.database
mongo.port = 27017
mongo.database = database
isMongoEnabled = true
```

**b) MongoClient bean :**

```
@Configuration
public class MongoConfiguration {

    @Value("#{'${mongo.hosts}'.split(',')}")
    private List<String> hosts;

    @Value("${mongo.port}")
    private int port;

    @Value("${isMongoEnabled}")
    private boolean isMongoEnabled;

    @Value("${mongo.database}")
    private String database;

    private Mongo createMongo() throws Exception {
        final List<ServerAddress> serverList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (final String host : hosts) {
            serverList.add(new ServerAddress(host, port));
        }
        return new MongoClient(serverList);
    }

    @Bean 
    public Mongo mongoClient() throws Exception {
            final Mongo mongo = createMongo();
            return mongo;
    }


}
```

**c) Template bean:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(
        basePackages = "com.abc.test",
        mongoTemplateRef = "customMongoNodeTemplate"
)

@Import(MongoConfiguration.class)
public class TemplateConfiguration {
    @Value("${mongo.database}")
        private String database;


        @Bean
        public MongoTemplate customMongoNodeTemplate(@Qualifier ("mongoClient") Mongo mongo) {
            final MongoDbFactory factory =  new SimpleMongoDbFactory( (MongoClient) mongo, database); 
            return new MongoTemplate(factory);

        }

}
```

**d) Exception:**

```
com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=127.0.0.1:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)}}]
```

UPDATE: 
After trying SimpleMongoClientDBFactory(uri) got below exception :

- Application.properties:

```
mongo.uri= mongodb://mongo-node-1.database:27017,mongo-node-2.database:27017,mongo-node-3.database:27017/database
```

Exception :

```
#com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=127.0.0.1:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)}}]
```

SPRING boot version :

```
2.1.6
```

Mongo version :

```
4.0.6
```

Mongo Driver Version:

```
3.8.2
```

Comment: Why are you trying to connect to `127.0.0.1` ? Is the mongodb running in the same pod as your application?

Comment: Make sure `public Mongo mongoClient() throws Exception` is called

Comment: @Valijon : i checked and pasted logs and ran its printed at startup but when query is called it tries and times out with same exception

Comment: @michalk: I verified using logs and saw correct URL loaded into serverAddress list but when i get exception its always 127.0.0.1. I feel its maybe because on nslookup I get the cluster ip itself. maybe thats why . Also I forgot to show URI property will add it

Comment: I have verified network configurations also No issues there as well

Comment: It's not a MongoDB issue, but Spring configuration. Even you are defining `MongoConfiguration`, spring-boot is loading standard configuration

Comment: @Valijon : surprisingly I checked same on my local and works perfect bot sure whats wrong . Any suggestions ?

Comment: Confirm please: Your spring-boot version + did you setup `@SpringBootApplication(exclude = MongoAutoConfiguration.class)`

Comment: @Valijon :
1) Version updated in question 
2) yes i have exclude included. On local your suggested changes also worked just like my changes but on server same issue

Comment: Let's us continue [chat.stackoverflow.com](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215947/discussion-between-valijon-and-jsingh)

Comment: @Valijon: I cant chat as it needs more reputation points than what i have

Comment: try again now, i've upvoted your question :)

Comment: I guess its not synced yet, I still can't

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215949/discussion-between-valijon-and-jsingh).

Answer (score 1):

### Spring-boot:2.3.0.RELEASE

1. Disable `@SpringBootApplication(exclude = MongoAutoConfiguration.class)`
2. To initiate `MongoTemplate` we can do with:

   - `MongoDatabaseFactory`
   - `com.mongodb.client.MongoClient` [interface] (Do not confuse with `com.mongodb.MongoClient` [class])

#### Implementation with `MongoDatabaseFactory`

**application.properties:**

```
mongo.uri=mongodb://mongo-node-1.database:27017,mongo-node-2.database:27017,mongo-node-3.database:27017/database
isMongoEnabled=true
```

**Template bean**

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "com.abc.test", mongoTemplateRef = "customMongoNodeTemplate")
public class TemplateConfiguration {
    @Value("${mongo.uri}")
    private String uri;

    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate customMongoNodeTemplate() {
        return new MongoTemplate(new SimpleMongoClientDatabaseFactory(uri));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello , Thank you very much firstly for the code recommendation. I got exception of format of url is not as expected error. Updating question with that exception

Answer (score 0):

So this was a issue from my end , Turns out some one committed a mongoClient recently in git and when i took pull , that was a new MongoClient() and on local went to localhost but on cluster failed. Code was fine from the start. Thank you very much for baring with me